# How to assign value to a variable in the loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress loop:

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    echo'<h3><a href="index.php?page_id=100">';the_title(); echo'</a></h3>';
    echo'<h4>'.the_excerpt().'</h4>
```

How can I assign post id value to a variable in this loop?

`$id = the_id();` don't work.

Comment: It don't assign value, it just print the id value. If i write `$idd = the_id(); echo '['. $idd.']';` The result is: `11 []`, result of `echo $idd` is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `get_the_ID()`.

All of the functions that start with `the_...` *print* the value. The functions that start with `get_the_...` *return* the value.